# Removing index.php in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-3, remote-server

My codeigniter project is working properly on the development server, but when I migrated this on live server I'm facing issue with the .htaccess file. I can't be removed index.php file. It gives an error 404 not found.

Comment: Make sure your server is configured to use .htaccess file.

Comment: Do you have mode-rewrite enabled for your production server?

Comment: Care to post `.htaccess` code if you think that is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i fixed this, follow below steps.

1. just follow steps CodeIgniter user guide- removing index.php from url.
2. Add .htaccess in root where application and system folders are located.
3. Set $config['base_url'] = 'http:/your domain IP/ci folder name';
   Note: path - ..config/config.php
4. Set $config['index_page'] = "";
   Note: path - ..config/config.php
5. imp. Add below code in httpd.conf file.

   ```
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   ```

   And restart the server. Fixed.

Comment: Don't use ip in domain base url your css and other links may not work `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';`

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter